# adding check boxes to my unordered list with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a project where i need to make a todo list and then when a user clicks the add button itll pull the info in and create a new li item and it to my ul list. But i need my li's to be created with a checkbox attribute attached to them  as well and i am stuck, My code is below

```js
// this creates a new li based on the entered value in the text box that it gets when you hit the button
function addItem() {
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let myLiValue = document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value;
  let liTextNode = document.createTextNode(myLiValue);
  newLi.appendChild(liTextNode);
  // this just makes sure a user cant enter in a blank value
  if (myLiValue == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Something Before Hitting Add Item");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('theNewList').appendChild(newLi);
    document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="main.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Brody's Wonderful List Of Things</h1>
    <h3>Enter a Item and Press "Add Item" to Add to Your List</h3>
    <section>
      <div class="">
        <label>Please Enter in Your TODO Item</label>
        <input type="text" id="textBoxAdd">
        <button type="button" id="addBtn" onclick="addItem()">Add Item</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul id="theNewList">
    
      </ul>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: *i am stuck* <-- What are you stuck on? What's your actual question? It seems like you know how to dynamically create and append an element. Just also create and append a checkbox.

Comment: i attempted to create the checkbox and append it but i couldn't seem to append it under the li with text, would i need to append then a input with type checkbox and then append my textnode to the check box?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your attempt and then add more specific details of what it is about your attempt that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

To add a checkbox you can use the following:

```
let newCheckBoxID = 'checkbox_' + myLiValue;
let newCheckBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
newCheckBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
newCheckBox.setAttribute("id", newCheckBoxID);
newLi.appendChild(newCheckBox);
```

You'll notice I added code to give the checkbox an ID.  Chances are that you'll want to use the value of the checkbox in code somewhere so making sure it has ID set would be necessary.  For actual use you'll want to massage the myLiValue to not have spaces and whatnot first before you make it part of an id.  Also, I would probably add that id to some array somewhere too as the checkboxes are created...

Next, I would consider putting your text in a LABEL tag instead of leaving it as raw text in the LI

```
let newCheckLabel = document.createElement('LABEL');
newCheckLabel.setAttribute('for', newCheckBoxID);
let labelTextNode = document.createTextNode(myLiValue);
newCheckLabel.appendChild(labelTextNode);
newLi.appendChild(newCheckLabel);
```

```js
// this creates a new li based on the entered value in the text box that it gets when you hit the button
function addItem() {
  let newLi = document.createElement("li");
  let myLiValue = document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value;
  let newCheckBoxID = 'checkbox_' + myLiValue;
    
  let newCheckBox = document.createElement("INPUT");
  newCheckBox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
  newCheckBox.setAttribute("id", newCheckBoxID);
  newLi.appendChild(newCheckBox);
  
  let newCheckLabel = document.createElement('LABEL');
  newCheckLabel.setAttribute('for', newCheckBoxID);
  let labelTextNode = document.createTextNode(myLiValue);
  newCheckLabel.appendChild(labelTextNode);
  newLi.appendChild(newCheckLabel);
  
  // this just makes sure a user cant enter in a blank value
  if (myLiValue == "") {
    alert("Please Enter Something Before Hitting Add Item");
  } else {
    document.getElementById('theNewList').appendChild(newLi);
    document.getElementById('textBoxAdd').value = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To-Do List</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="main.js" async></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>Brody's Wonderful List Of Things</h1>
    <h3>Enter a Item and Press "Add Item" to Add to Your List</h3>
    <section>
      <div class="">
        <label>Please Enter in Your TODO Item</label>
        <input type="text" id="textBoxAdd">
        <button type="button" id="addBtn" onclick="addItem()">Add Item</button>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section>
      <ul id="theNewList">
    
      </ul>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: To be curious, why downcheck?  I showed how a usable checkbox can be added to each LI created.  And talked to making sure its value can be referenced later if needed.  The OP should have enough info to have learned what needs to happen and how to adjust it for his own style preferences/needs

Comment: [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Edited my answer to include more full description and provide extra insights for tying the text to the checkbox using Label instead of raw text in LI